# SSH to user from external network says permission denied, works fine from internal network

Tags: ssh, openstack, ip, openssh

Okay, I have Openstack installed on a server.

I can SSH to the openstack server

I have set port forwarding on that server

I can ssh to the instance using private AND public(floating) IPs when done from internal network

BUT,

when i try ssh user@public.ip ,from outside the servers network, i do reach the ssh server and i am asked for password, but even after entering the correct password, it does not accept it..

asks for it 3 times, n finally says,

> Permission denied (publickey,password)

I have also tried changing permissions of the .ssh directory and its contents as well as the owners for the same, but that doesn't work either...

what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that your connection is definitely reaching the target server, and you're not attempting to get a shell on the host machine by mistake?

I'd suggest using a combination of tcpdump and log inspection on the target server (once logged in internally) to confirm that your login attempts are being received correctly.

On the target host, you can use tcpdump as follows:

`tcpdump -i any src host [ip_your_connecting_from]`

During your connection attempts, also check the authlog to see if it's logging the attempts:

`tail -f /var/log/auth.log`

(all commands should be run as root or sudo)